# JSON Array Not Parsing As Expected

Tags: javascript, json, ejs

I have my data structured as follows..

```
[{"type" : "text", "label" : "Some Label"},{"type" : "Other type", "label": "Other label"}],[{"type" : "text", "label" : "Some Label"},{"type" : "Other type", "label": "Other label"}]
```

I retrieve this data from a data tag with

```
var formData = $(document.getElementById('form-render-data')).data('form');
```

I cannot iterate over each array and access each object inside it. I have tried parsing and stringifying with surrounding [] but it makes no difference.

Looping through using index just prints each character in the string. I am not stringifying it before it is being put in the data tag either.

**Update:**
As there has been some confusion over what I have been trying to achieve I will try to best explain the full process.

Forms are being built using Formbuilder.io. I am then exporting the JSON data from the forms and storing them in a MYSQL db using the Sails JS framework. However, there is the possibility of multiple forms being made for one session, hence the need for multiple arrays. I'm then returning the JSON in a request without any Stringifying or Parsing.

I have tried wrapping the JSON in square brackets too but I'm still not having any luck.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - you tell us you parsed the data but how can we know?

Comment: @mplungjan: The OP is using jQuery's [`data` function](http://api.jquery.com/data/), which will parse JSON if found on a `data-*` attribute during initialization, provided the JSON is valid.

Comment: Right - I was not sure that worked - by why not `$('#form-render-data').data('form');` then

Comment: As mplungjan points out, we can't possibly help you without more information. In particular, we need to see the HTML that defines the `data-form` attribute on the `form-render-data` element.

Comment: @mplungjan: I can't think of any good reason, as jQuery will look at that selector and call `getElementById` anyway. :-)

Comment: Also the JSON is invalid which will explain a lot

Comment: that's not a valid JSON... it is basically 2 arrays

Comment: Er...yes, yes, it does. :-)

Comment: @Jonathan he said he wants to iterate over arrayS, he knows there are two

Answer (score 1):

Your code works if you fix the JSON

```js
var formData = $('#form-render-data').data('form');
console.log(formData)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form-render-data" data-form='[{"type" : "text", "label" : "Some Label"},{"type" : "Other type", "label": "Other label"},
{"type" : "text", "label" : "Some Label"},{"type" : "Other type", "label": "Other label"}]'>Data</div>
```

If not, you cannot parse the .data, but need attr("data-form") and a split

```js
var formData = $('#form-render-data').attr('data-form');
console.log(JSON.parse(formData.split('],[').join(",")))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form-render-data" data-form='[{"type" : "text", "label" : "Some Label"},{"type" : "Other type", "label": "Other label"}],[{"type" : "text", "label" : "Some Label"},{"type" : "Other type", "label": "Other label"}]'>Data</div>
```

or a wrap

```js
var formData = $('#form-render-data').attr('data-form');
console.log(JSON.parse("["+formData+"]"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form-render-data" data-form='[{"type" : "text", "label" : "Some Label"},{"type" : "Other type", "label": "Other label"}],[{"type" : "text", "label" : "Some Label"},{"type" : "Other type", "label": "Other label"}]'>Data</div>
```

Comment: As pointed out in the comments on my initial post, I am aware there are multiple top level arrays in my example. I have tried to surround my json with [ and ] to make it an array of arrays before parsing it but I'm having no such luck.

Comment: Please see update

Comment: @BenBrookes: If you want an array of arrays, you literally put `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end of what you have: `[[{"type" : "text", "label" : "Some Label"},{"type" : "Other type", "label": "Other label"}],[{"type" : "text", "label" : "Some Label"},{"type" : "Other type", "label": "Other label"}]]`. Now you have an array of arrays, which is valid JSON.

Comment: Link demonstrating that's valid: https://jsonlint.com/?json=%5B%5B%7B%22type%22%20%3A%20%22text%22%2C%20%22label%22%20%3A%20%22Some%20Label%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%20%3A%20%22Other%20type%22%2C%20%22label%22%3A%20%22Other%20label%22%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22type%22%20%3A%20%22text%22%2C%20%22label%22%20%3A%20%22Some%20Label%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%20%3A%20%22Other%20type%22%2C%20%22label%22%3A%20%22Other%20label%22%7D%5D%5D

Comment: *"If not you cannot use the .data"* Yes, they can; they'll get it as a string. If `data` can't parse what it finds (as a number, as JSON, etc.), it returns it as a string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I added the wrap

Answer (score 0):

You have nested `JSON` within an array. So, you have to treat it as such.

```
var formData = $('#form-render-data').data('form');

for(var i = 0; i < formData.length; i++) {
    console.log(formData[i].type);
    console.log(formData[i].label);
}
```

It will iterate over your arrays, logging the object properties to the console.

Fix you array data like so:

```
[
    {
        "type" : "text",
        "label" : "Some Label"
    },
    {
        "type" : "Other type",
        "label": "Other label"
    }
,
    {
        "type" : "text",
        "label" : "Some Label"
    },
    {
        "type" : "Other type",
        "label": "Other label"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a working example - I believe the build-in JSON.parse will fail

Comment: @mplungjan Works for me

Comment: Not  using OP's data: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9vha87dx/ - you changed his data just like I did